# Warning: Cannot update a component (`Unknown`) while rendering a different component

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I'm trying to pass the **clientId** from the parent block to a child block.  I need to stuff the **clientId** into an attribute value.  When I use **setAttribute** trying to assign the value to **sliderId**, I get the following warning:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`Unknown`) while rendering a different component (`Test2Edit`).
```

What is the Gutenberg (JSX) way to solve this?

My test block is as follows:

`gc-x-test/block.json`

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "give-camp/gc-x-test",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "GC Test",
    "category": "text",
    "icon": "slides",
    "description": "Generic test",
    "attributes": {
        "sliderId": { "type": "string", "default": "s-01" }
    },
    "supports": {
        "type": "object",
        "anchor":   true
    },
    "textdomain": "give-camp-blocks",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js"
}
```

`gc-x-test/index.js`

```
import {
    registerBlockType
} from '@wordpress/blocks';
import metadata from './block.json';
import {
    useBlockProps
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
//
function Test2Edit(props) {
    //
    const {
        attributes: { sliderId },
        setAttributes,
        clientId,
    } = props;
    setAttributes( { sliderId: clientId } ); // see providesContext
    const blockProps = useBlockProps( );
    //
    return (
        <div
            { ...blockProps }
            >
            <div>1 of ?</div>
        </div>
    );
    //
};
//
function Test2Save( props ) {
    //
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save( );
    return (
        <div
            { ...blockProps }
            >
            <div>1 of ?</div>
        </div>
    );
    //
};
//
registerBlockType( metadata.name, {
    apiVersion: metadata.apiVersion,
    title: metadata.title,
    supports: metadata.supports,
    attributes: metadata.attributes,
    //
    edit: Test2Edit,
    save: Test2Save,
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw a React.js post on useEffect and then looked for examples on Gutenberg source as follows:

```
...
import {
    useEffect
} from '@wordpress/element';
...
function Test2Edit(props) {
    ...
    useEffect( () => {
        setAttributes( { sliderId: clientId } );
    }, [ clientId ] );
    ...
```